# Como fazer um "git pull" em pastas específicas do repositório

Tags: git, github

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto onde dentro do repositório tenho algumas pastas de suporte para o ambiente de desenvolvimento, porem não gostaria de publicá-las em produção. Nosso sistema utiliza o git pull para baixar as atualizações, desta forma as pastas restritas ao ambiente de homologação estão indo para produção também.

Gostaria de efetuar um git pull seletivo somente no ambiente de produção, já no ambiente de homologação fazer o git pull completo.

Alguma sugestão de como resolver esse caso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui achar a solução, resolvi o problema ativando uma opção de sparseCheckout, conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
git config core.sparseCheckout true
echo "pasta1/" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
echo "pasta2/" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
echo "pasta3/" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
git pull origin main
```

Desta forma consegui definir somente o pull das pastas informadas acima.

Answer (score 2):

**Solução para um "git pull seletivo":**

```
git fetch
git checkout <remote>/<branch> -- /caminho/*
```

**Explicação:**

`git fetch`

> Isso fará download de todas as atualizações do repositório remoto, mas
> não colocará em sua area de trabalho git

`git checkout <remote>/<branch> -- /caminho/*`

> Isso pegará todas as atualicações baixadas por git fetch do repositório remoto `<remote>` e
> branch `<branch>` que estão no diretorio `/caminho/` e colocará em seu diretório correspondente na
> area de trabalho

**`<remote>`**: nome dado ao git remote que referencia seu repositório remoto (origin, por exemplo)

**`<branch>`**: nome da branch em que vc está trabalhando (main, por exemplo)

Feito isso, vc terá seu repositório sincronizado com relação apenas ao diretório /caminho/

Comment: Consigo apontar mais de uma pasta desta forma?